# hibernate error on spring project

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i'm getting an error when i'm trying to compile the mvc project i hope there is someone can help me on identifying the cause of problem .
i provide there the the stack trace and the `applicationContext.xml` file

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- Création de la datasource -->
<bean id="datasource"   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/persistance"></property>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>
    <property name="password" value="ensien"></property>
    </bean>
    <!--  <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
    <list>
    <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>-->
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <!-- On spécifie ici les lieux où trouver les fichiers de persistence -->
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- On spécifie ici les sources de données à utiliser, locale ou distante -->
        <property name="dataSources">
            <map>
                <entry key="localDataSource" value-ref="datasource" />
                <!--<entry key="remoteDataSource" value-ref="remote-db" />-->
            </map>
        </property>
        <!-- On spécifie ici la sources de données par défaut si aucune source de données n'est disponible -->
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean>
    <!--  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ERP_PCD"></property>
    </bean>-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ERP_PCD"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean> 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean name="opmanager" class="com.ensi.dao.opmanagerImpl"> </bean>
    <bean name="metier"  class="org.ensi.metier.TestImpl">
    <property name="op" ref="opmanager"></property>
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ensi.dao"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

**error warnings**

```
1197 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
1489 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
1800 [main] INFO org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
1885 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1294a25c: defining beans [datasource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,entityManager,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,opmanager,metier,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
1926 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'ERP_PCD'
2175 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
2181 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
2186 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
2193 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
2541 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1294a25c: defining beans [datasource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,entityManager,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,opmanager,metier,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/housseminfo/workspace/ERP_PCD/target/classes/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.ensi.dao.Maintest.main(Maintest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ejb3Configuration.java:1420)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1390)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1183)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:94)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using `Hibernate 3.3.1.GA` but you need `hibernate-core 3.6.0` or higher to call `addAnnotatedClass` of `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`